# passing data from array of hash in ruby into javascript full calendar

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, fullcalendar

I am trying pass a value from data at index from ruby :

in user.rb file :

```
list = [{:date=>"07 Mar", :price => "1000,00", :fruit=>"Orange"},
 {:date=>"07 Mar", :price => "2000,00", :fruit=>"Apple"}]
```

to Js in full_calendar.js :

```
dayRender:function(date, cell){
  var array = <%= j @list.to_json %>;
  $(cell).html('<span>' + array + '</span>');
  },
```

in full calendar and I can't make it work. I have tried a lot of different options so far and can't find any solution to access at list one of the value at index 0, 1, or 2...

Any ideas?

Comment: your ruby code in wich file are? (also you have `list` not `@list`)

Comment: If your ruby code is outputting JSON, you need to parse it before you can access the properties. (`JSON.parse`)

Comment: Where is come from the variable(`@list`) and in which js file you're using it?

Comment: I have edited my question with answers to your questions. I have tried JSON.parse too

Comment: It's still unclear for me, where is come from that js file, is it in `app/assets/javascripts` folder? or `app/views/` ? What is `user.rb` ? is it a model file?

Comment: @Зелёный yes js is located inside `app/assets/javascripts folder` and `user.rb` is a model file

Comment: I suggest you to read some basic, how is javascript and Rails works. http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split up the server and client part and test each.
First Ruby: You will need something like this, test it first in a separate Ruby script.

```
require 'json'
@list = [{:date=>"07 Mar", :price => "1000,00", :fruit=>"Orange"}, {:date=>"07 Mar", :price => "2000,00", :fruit=>"Apple"}]
@list.to_json
# [{"date":"07 Mar","price":"1000,00","fruit":"Orange"},{"date":"07 Mar","price":"2000,00","fruit":"Apple"}]
```

Then the client part: put yout Ruby code in a place where you can see the result in javascript. Make sure you get json required somewhere in the line.

```
dayRender:function(date, cell){
  var array = <%=
    require 'json'
    @list = [{:date=>"07 Mar", :price => "1000,00", :fruit=>"Orange"}, {:date=>"07 Mar", :price => "2000,00", :fruit=>"Apple"}]
    @list.to_json
  %>;
  console.log(array);
  $(cell).html('<span>' + array + '</span>');
  },
```

If that works, it's a matter of testing if your @list variable is known in the erb file. If not concentrate on passing this variable, is your erb file in the right path ? Is your route correct ? etc.

```
dayRender:function(date, cell){
  var array = <%=@list.to_json %>;
  $(cell).html('<span>' + array + '</span>');
  },
```

As an extra: make you some simple test script where you can extract your problem, test it without having to bother about other influences and above all can publish here in case you can't figure it out.
You ask this for rails but I use Sinatra most of the time, so you will have to do the same for Rails. In case you don't know Sinatra, put all of this in app.rb and run.

```
require 'sinatra' # gem install sinatra
require "sinatra/reloader" #so that you don't have restart the server after changes
require 'json'

get '/' do
  @list = [{:date=>"07 Mar", :price => "1000,00", :fruit=>"Orange"}, {:date=>"07 Mar", :price => "2000,00", :fruit=>"Apple"}]
  erb :index
end
__END__
@@ index
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var array = <%=@list.to_json%>;
    console.log(array);
  });
</script>
<body>
</body>
```

And yes, I get your json in the console..

Comment: thanks for your answer @peter it got me started. The following started me on the right path, I know have to iterate through the objects to catch by date each value I need to load in the corresponding cells.    `dayRender:function(date, cell){
      var json = <%= 
        require 'json'
        (@list.to_json.html_safe
        %>;
      $(cell).html('<td>' + (JSON.stringify(json, null, 4)) + '</td>');
    },`